# HiddenField javascript value chanded from server confirm on client side

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to check on client side that the `HiddenField` has been update from server?

Updating 2 images every 5 second by client side:

```
 __doPostBack('UpdatePanel', '');
```

Server side:

```
 HiddenField1_Foto.Value = Foto(random)
```

Client side:

```
image.src = document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1_Foto.ClientID %>').value;
```

A lot of time a new image doesnt show up like hasnot been load yet,but the server did update `document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1_Foto.ClientID %>').value;`

How to check that the images has been load?

Answer (score 0):

image.onload = function () {} - did the job